# Windows 7 cannot connect wirelessly to Netgear Router WPN824 V2

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I have a new HP laptop running Windows 7 Home Premium with an Atheros Wireless card. I have a Netgear WPN824 V2 Rangemax router. The router works with a wired connection. Wirelessly it can see the network but it cannot connect.

I have searched the web and the WPN824 seems to work for some people, but I cannot get it to connect. I have tried disabling Bonjour Service and a few other things but it continues not to connect.

Am I probably correct to assume that the WPN824 is somehow incompatible with Windows 7? Or am I missing some simple change I should make?

Comment: What sort of encryption are you using? Have you tried with no encryption at all?